# Prove $f(\xi)$ behaves as $e^{\xi^2}$ if $\lambda<0$ in $\frac{d^2f}{d\xi^2}-2\xi\frac{df}{d\xi}+2\lambda f(\xi)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, special-functions, quantum-mechanics, hermite-polynomials

> How does one show that $f(\xi)$ will behave as $e^{\xi^2}$ if $\lambda<0$ in the Hermite differential equation $\frac{d^2f}{d\xi^2}-2\xi\frac{df}{d\xi}+2\lambda f(\xi)=0$

This problem comes in solving the linearly independent Schrodinger equation correpsonds to a 1D harmonic oscillator.

It says since $f(\xi)$ behaves as $e^{\xi^2}$ if $\lambda<0$, $f(\xi)\to +\infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$, the corresponding solutions are physically not desirable, thus $\lambda \geq0$.

how do I prove that $f(\xi)$ behaves as $e^{\xi^2}$ if $\lambda<0$ mathematically ?

**Note:** I understand how to solve the Hermite differential equation when $\lambda\geq 0$ to obtain Hermite functions of different order using the Power series method.

**Reference:** Page 74 of [ONE DIMENSIONAL HARMONIC OSCILLATOR](http://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/19444/1/Unit-16.pdf)

[image: img]

**Possible Way**

As I have seen in some [reference](http://www.niser.ac.in/%7Esbasak/p303_2010/07.09.pdf),

Making use of the Frobenius method, taking $f(\xi)=\xi^s\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_r\xi^r$

$$
\frac{a_{r+2}}{a_r}=\frac{2(r+s-\lambda)}{(r+s+2)(r+s+1)}=\frac{2(1+\frac{s}{r}-\frac{\lambda}{r})}{r(1+\frac{s+2}{r})(1+\frac{s+1}{r})}\bigg|_{r\to\infty}\to \frac{2}{r}
$$

Consider the series $e^{\xi^2}=1+\xi^2+\frac{\xi^4}{2!}+\cdots$. The ratio of the adjacent terms is
$$
\frac{b_{r+2}}{b_r}=\frac{(r/2)!}{(\frac{r+2}{2})!}=\frac{\bigg(\dfrac{r}{2}\bigg)!}{\bigg(\dfrac{r+2}{2}\bigg)!}=\frac{1}{\frac{r}{2}+1}\bigg|_{r\to\infty}\to \frac{2}{r}
$$
asymptotically, $f(\xi)$ is behaving like $e^{\xi^2}$, thus $\psi=e^{-\xi^2/2}f(\xi)$ goes like $e^{+\xi^2/2}$.

Is it a well defined explanation ?

Comment: You could solve the ODE by [using the power series method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations).

Comment: Have you figured out what diff. eq. $fe^{-\xi^2}$ satisfies?

Comment: @mattos if $\lambda\geq 0$ I think the series terminate, then I understand how to solve using the powerseries method to obtain all the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Substituting $e^{-\xi^2/2}f(\xi)$ in the original equation leads to the one that I have mentioned

Comment: It must depend on the initial values of $f$ and $f'$. It could be useful because the equation can be rewritten $\mathrm{e}^{\xi^2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f'\right)'(\xi)=-2\lambda f(\xi)$ which can have a sign for large $\xi$ and then implies some growing properties for $\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f(\xi)$.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the reference, in case I didnt explain it clearly.

Comment: You are using $f$ and $\Psi$ inconsistently. Please fix the text of your question so that others don't have to spend their time figuring out what you are asking.

Comment: @Nicolas I have edited OP to include a posssible attmept I have come across in a reference, could you possible comment on that ?

Comment: @ss1729 Certainly Frobenius methods is a possible way to go. If your computation is correct (I did not check the indicial roots and so on), then you indeed get the announced result -- take care: $\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2/2}f(\xi)\sim\mathrm{e}^{+\xi^2/2}$ (there is a typo in your post).
By the way, it is said "From our earlier discussion, you can easily..." so Frobenius method was employed before in your lecture/textbook?

Comment: @K.defaoite Page 3 of http://www.niser.ac.in/~sbasak/p303_2010/07.09.pdf , is where I have found that explanation.

Comment: Apologies - I made a mistake when evaluating the limit. It holds generally, not asymptotically. Let me have a second look.

Comment: @Nicolas Could you please elaborate on your earlier explanation on how rewriting the equation in the form $e^{\xi^2}(e^{-\xi^2}f')'(\xi)=-2\lambda f(\xi)$ say anything about behavior of $e^{-\xi^2}f(\xi)$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 I meant that $-2\lambda>0$ so you could possibly obtain that $\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f'\right)'>0$ provided that you know that $f(\xi)>0$, then deduce that $\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f'$ is increasing and deduce that $f(\xi)\gtrsim\mathrm{e}^{\xi^2}$. This needs to show that $f(\xi)>0$ for $\xi\gg0$ which is maybe not the best idea anymore now you have two different answers here.

Comment: @Nicolas I still don't completely understand your approach. from the equation $(e^{-\xi^2}f'(\xi))'>0\implies e^{-\xi^2}f'(\xi)$ is increasing function. Its clear. I think, since $e^{-\xi^2}$ is decreasing, $f'(\xi)$ must be increasing, right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Yes that's right! If $\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f'\right)'>0$ then there exists an increasing function $r(\xi)$ such that $\mathrm{e}^{-\xi^2}f'(\xi)=r(\xi)$ (and since $r'(\xi)>0$, we have $r(\xi)>C>0$ by integration). Then the differential equality $f'(\xi)=r(\xi)\mathrm{e}^{\xi^2}$ implies that $f(\xi)\sim\mathrm{e}^{\xi^2}$ as $\xi\to+\infty$. That was the idea.

Comment: @Nicolas how does one conclude that $f'(\xi)=r(\xi)e^{\xi^2}\implies f(\xi)\approx e^{\xi^2}$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 It's because $r(\xi)>C$ for some constant $C$ (we integrate the differential inequality $r'(\xi)>0$). Take $\xi_0>0$ say; as $r$ is increasing, $r(\xi)>r(\xi_0)=:r_0$ and thus $f'(\xi)\geq r_0\mathrm{e}^{\xi^2}$. It remains to integrate this new differential inequality.

Answer (score 1):

### The long story short is that the exponential approximation is only valid if $\boldsymbol{|\lambda|}$ is close to $\boldsymbol1$. The explanation is below.

Putting $\lambda\to -\lambda$ into the equation we have
$$y''-2xy'-2\lambda y=0$$
The solution to this equation can be obtained via a power series approach. We can write
$$y(x;\lambda)=c_1\cdot M\left(\frac{\lambda}{2};\frac{1}{2}~\bigg|~x^2\right)+ c_2\cdot 2^{-\lambda}U\left(\frac{-\lambda}{2};\frac{1}{2}~\bigg|~x^{2}\right) $$
These are the [confluent hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) of the first and second kind. The strange delimiters in the arguments is a stylistic choice due to their relation to the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html). **IF** $y$ satisfies the convenient conditions $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$ then we can discard the confluent hypergeometric of the second kind and write
$$y(x;\lambda)= M\left(\frac{\lambda}{2};\frac{1}{2}~\bigg|~x^2\right)$$
$M$ is defined as
$$M(a;b~|~z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{a+i}{b+i}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right]$$
Which would mean that
$$M\left(\frac{\lambda}{2};\frac{1}{2}~\bigg|~x^2\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\lambda/2+i}{1/2+i}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1+2i/\lambda}{1+2i}\frac{(\sqrt{\lambda}~x)^{2k}}{k!}\right]$$
Assuming $\lambda$ is close to $1$ the product vanishes and we have
$$y(x;\lambda)=M\left(\frac{\lambda}{2};\frac{1}{2}~\bigg|~x^2\right)\approx\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{\lambda}~x)^{2k}}{k!}=\exp\left(\lambda x^2\right).$$

> Making use of the Frobenius method, taking $f(\xi)=\xi^s\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_r\xi^r$

> $$
> \frac{a_{r+2}}{a_r}=\frac{2(r+s-\lambda)}{(r+s+2)(r+s+1)}=\frac{2(1+\frac{s}{r}-\frac{\lambda}{r})}{r(1+\frac{s+2}{r})(1+\frac{s+1}{r})}\bigg|_{r\to\infty}\to \frac{2}{r}
> $$
> Consider the series $e^{\xi^2}=1+\xi^2+\frac{\xi^4}{2!}+\cdots$. The ratio of the adjacent terms is
> $$
> \frac{b_{r+2}}{b_r}=\frac{(r/2)!}{(\frac{r+2}{2})!}=\frac{\bigg(\dfrac{r}{2}\bigg)!}{\bigg(\dfrac{r+2}{2}\bigg)!}=\frac{1}{\frac{r}{2}+1}\bigg|_{r\to\infty}\to \frac{2}{r}
> $$
> asymptotically, $f(\xi)$ is behaving like $e^{\xi^2}$, thus $\psi=e^{-\xi^2/2}f(\xi)$ goes like $e^{-\xi^2/2}$.

This is OK, but we can think of pathological examples that don't follow this reasoning. Consider the two functions $e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and $\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ and
$$b_{n} =\begin{cases}
0 & n=2k\\
\frac{1}{n!} & n=4k+1\\
\frac{-1}{n!} & n=4k+3
\end{cases}$$
It is true that for odd $n$,
$$\frac{a_{n+4}}{a_n}=\frac{b_{n+4}}{b_n}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}$$
But I think it would be foolish to say $\sin(x)\to e^x$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I have added a possibe attempt in OP, could you please comment on that ?

Comment: @ss1729 See updated answer.